# How to shrink deeply nested list to space remaining in window so that page doesn't scroll but list shrinks and can be scrolled

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Here is the solution.

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.playlist-page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.playlist-header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.playlist-fill {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.playlist-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.playlist-row {
  height: 100%;
}

.playlist-pane {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.playlist-pane-header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.playlist-list {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

Notes:

100vh, 100vw means 100% of the viewport height and width.

height: 100%; in child elements is always relative to the direct parent, if the direct parent does not have a height specified 100% will do nothing. This is why I must specify height: 100%; in .playlist-container and .playlist-row.

body has position: relative; and .playlist-page has position:absolute; because in React .playlist-page will not be a direct child of body and we will not be able to set height: 100%; for all the intervening parents.

flexshrink: 1; needs min-height: 0; and max-height: 100%; to force the element to shrink smaller than its content.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shrinklist.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Testi ng!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="playlist-page">
      <div class="playlist-header">
        <button class="btn" color="primary">Import</button>
      </div>
      <p />
      <div class="playlist-fill">
        <div class="container-fluid playlist-container">
          <div class="row playlist-row">
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 playlist-pane">
              <div class="playlist-pane-header">
                <button class="btn">Playlist:</button>
                <p />
              </div>
              <div class="list-group playlist-list">
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 playlist-pane">
              <div class="playlist-pane-header">
                <button class="btn">Playlist:</button>
                <p />
              </div>
              <div class="list-group playlist-list">
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item playlist-item">
                  <p>image &ensp; title</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Executable:

https://codesandbox.io/s/long-leftpad-ltx97

Open the preview in a new window and resize it vertically. When the contents of the list boxes are taller than the page, the scrollbars will appear.

Comment: Add your html or jsx. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it with the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution again I must type at least 30 characters.

https://codesandbox.io/s/long-leftpad-ltx97